# Excel: how to return True if every value in the two column match?

Tags: excel

How do I return TRUE if and only if every cell in two columns matches with one another?

For example, let's say I have this data:
[image]

This should return FALSE because the the data in row 7 do not match.

However, 
[image]

this should return TRUE because every row in the two columns have the same values.

I would really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: are you looking for a cell formula or a macro solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$7=$B$2:$B$7))=COUNTA($A$2:$A$7)
```

Comment: I see. Learned how to use it!!